# Even and Odd numbers

Tags: c++

The program should prompt the user for one character option (either ‘e’, ‘E’ or ‘o’, ‘O’).

It should respond in the following ways: 
•   If user enters character option ‘e’ or ‘E’ then it should display the even numbers from 1 to 50. 
•   If user enters character option ‘o’ or ‘O’ then it should display the odd numbers from 1 to 50.

The following is my code but its not compiling in the dev.cpp environment you people have a look and correct me if there is any mistake ...?

```
#include <iostream>;

int main()
{
     using namespace std;
     int i=1;
     char ch;
     cout<<"please enter a choice"<<endl;
     cin>>ch;
     switch(ch){
     case 'e':
     case 'E':i=2;break;
     case 'o':
     case 'O':break;
     default:
     cout<<"Wrong input."<<endl;
     system ("pause");
     exit(1);
}
     while (i<50)
     cout<<i<<" ",i+=2;

}
```

Comment: Sorry there was an error the code was not there before but now I have add the code have a look on it please and correct me ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Remove the ";" after the #include
- Add the `#include <cstdlib>` to get `system` and `exit`

The following compiled for me:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
     using namespace std;
     int i=1;
     char ch;
     cout<<"please enter a choice"<<endl;
     cin>>ch;
     switch(ch){
     case 'e':
     case 'E':i=2;break;
     case 'o':
     case 'O':break;
     default:
         cout<<"Wrong input."<<endl;
         system ("pause");
         exit(1);
     }
     while (i<50)
         cout<<i<<" ",i+=2;    
}
```

Comment: Thankyou its compiled but after giving an option for example e or E the cmd window should remain open and ask for another input what command should I add in it ?

Comment: Well, you could try putting a for or while loop round the lot.